# Проверка типа данных

Tags: java, jdbc

Ввожу данные в БД и все проходит отлично. Но как сделать проверку вводимого типа, чтоб пользователь не сломал программу?

```
public void addNumber() throws SQLException {

    String INSERT = "insert into telephonebook.phonenumbers(name, number) values (?, ?)";
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT);

    System.out.print("Enter name and surname ==> ");
    String name = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter number ==> ");
    int number = scanner.nextInt();

    preparedStatement.setString(1, name);
    preparedStatement.setInt(2, number);
    preparedStatement.execute();

}
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что значит "не сломал программу"? Если я ввожу плохие данные, должно вылезти предупреждение и какая-то попытка ввода? Или просто сообщение о том, что я плохо ввел и программа продолжит работать дальше?

Comment: Да, вы правы. "Если я ввожу плохие данные, должно вылезти предупреждение и какая-то попытка ввода?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете отталкиваться от такой конструкции:

```
while (!scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println("incorrect input");
    scanner.next();
}
int number = scanner.nextInt();
```

Comment: Спасибо, вы мне помогли.